# Is there a way to navigate using table of contents in DocView mode?

Tags: docview

Is there a way to navigate in DocView mode(for pdfs) to particular section using the section title instead of page number?

Comment: I strongly recommend [`pdf-tools`](https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools) for reading PDF documents in Emacs. `pdf-view-mode`, which is part of `pdf-tools`, has a lot more functionality than `doc-view-mode`. Following links is also possible.

Comment: I'm planning to stick to default emacs modes as much as possible.  pdf-tools looks great, but all my requirements are covered by DocView mode except for navigation using sections. So, wondering if this feature is already provided by DocView or if there is any hack which I could use.

Answer (score 0):

In Emacs 29, this feature is supported by default, allowing you to navigate with Imenu (default shortcut: M-g i) when mutool is installed.